# Can't get error message for PSQLException

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, exception, spring-data-jpa

I've developed an API service, which add some data to the database. I've put unique constraint for the `name` field of my entity. Whenever I try to insert duplicate `name` value, I gives following stack trace.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_tten_courseservice_program_table_program_name"
  Detail: Key (program_name)=(jkjkncj) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 119 more
```

This is one of the nested exception, from which I want the error message to send to front end. And the root exception is:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [uk_tten_courseservice_program_table_program_name]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

What I've added in my entity class is as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tten_courseservice_program_table", uniqueConstraints = {
                        @UniqueConstraint(name = "uk_tten_courseservice_program_table_program_name", columnNames = { "program_name" }) })
public class Program {

    @Column(name = "program_name")
    private String programName;
    //other attributes and getter setters. 
}
```

So what I'm missing here? I've tried placing:

```
catch(PSQLexception e)
```

but it does not catch my error because it's not the root exception. And `DataIntegrityException` has very vague message like:

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [uk_tten_courseservice_program_table_program_name]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Is there any other ways to achieve these? One way I know is to run search query on database before saving each and every record to check whether it's already there or not, but I think it won't be efficient. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the code which throws the exception and where you are catching it?

Comment: When I write repository.save(), it violates the db constraint and exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

To handle such exceptions you can implement [ExceptionHandler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc). To get root cause of the exception you can use utility method `org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils#getMostSpecificCause`.

Example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> conflict(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {

        String message = NestedExceptionUtils.getMostSpecificCause(e).getMessage();
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(message); 
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

Where `ErrorMessage` is your custom error message class.

Additional info: https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but I don't understand where to put this code?

Comment: In you project )) It's standalone class. Se more examples in the links I provided...

Comment: Of course in my project but at which layer? Controller, service?

Comment: In web-layer (see [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)).